# Multiple TypeScript `import` statements for single module

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.8

Especially during refactoring, I prefer distinct `import` statements from a visual, conceptual, and workflow perspective:

```
import {Component}      from 'angular2/core';
import {Input}          from 'angular2/core';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
```

as opposed to the more common inline form:

```
import {Component, Input, enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
```

or the wrapped inline form:

```
import {
   Component, 
   Input, 
   enableProdMode
   }                    from 'angular2/core';
```

The TS compiler should be savvy enough to address this, but I don't know that it is. Are there any negative consequence to the generated JavaScript in *TypeScript 1.8+* for using multiple *TypeScript* `import` statements for one module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer to have every object imported in a different line just for the sake of what you're viewing you can do this:

```
import {
  Component, 
  Input, 
  enableProdMode
} from 'angular2/core';
```

**EDIT:**

The difference in the generated code is that in the case of multiple imports for the same module will generate different variables. In your case, you might have a js compiled code like this (if you're compiling to commonjs):

```
var angular2_core_1 = require('angular2/core');
var angular2_core_2 = require('angular2/core');
var angular2_core_3 = require('angular2/core');
```

If you have only one import you will have only one variable.

In any case, modules are singleton, so it does not matter that you importing the same module multiple times, there will always be only one instance of each module.

Comment: Thanks, @VinTem -- yes, I'm aware of that; I should have been more clear. I use distinct `imports` for sorting, grouping, de-duplication workflows during refactoring so this form won't work in my use-case. I'll add a bit to my question.

Comment: Consider separating the singleton module aspect into a separate answer, @VinTem.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript will generate three `require` calls:

```
var core_1 = require('angular2/core');
var core_2 = require('angular2/core');
var core_3 = require('angular2/core');
```

nevertheless each module will be loaded only once. The size of generated JavaScript code will slightly increase.